# ":unmatched" error while installing flutter

Tags: flutter, terminal, zsh, zshrc

> Last login: Fri Mar 19 15:57:11 on ttys000 /Users/me/.zshrc:3:
> unmatched " me@MacBook-Pro ~ %

what does that mean?
I'm trying to install flutter.

Comment: It means you have an opening `"` without a closing `"` in your .zshrc

Comment: thank you responding. i'm very new at this.  how do I go back and close it?

Comment: I don't remember what I did...

Comment: Open `/Users/me/.zshrc` in a text editor

Comment: I tried that and nothing happened

Comment: What do you mean? Were you not able to open the file in a text editor? Why not?

Comment: @LeenaMarie: _nothing happend_ .... What did you expect to happen, after you open a file in a text editor? A beautiful sunset? When I am running a file throught the text editor, I can see the file and edit it. That's what editors are made for. If you can't spot the unmatched quote in this file with your eyes, use a tool such as [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), or do it the tedious way: Erase (comment out) all lines from .zshrc, and uncomment them then one by one until the problem re-appears. Then you know at least where the culprit is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Open the file /Users/me/.zshrc [this is the file where you were trying to add the path for flutter]

2- Look for the line that is missing a '', and add that ''. [most likely it's going to be the line you added with flutter], so look there first.

3- Save your file and exit.

4- then in your terminal, run this command: `source ~/.zshrc` this will refresh your .zshrc file.

Comment: ...how do I open the file Users/me/.zshrc ? I typed it in sublime text but nothing happened, was something supposed to? I also tried typing it in terminal but it said zsh: no such file or directory

Comment: from your terminal type:
nano ~/.zshrc

or

vim ~/.zshrc

do your edits, save and exit. Google 'How to exit vim', you're going to need it.

Comment: @LeenaMarie : Just a recommendation: There are plenty of comfortable text editors available for nearly every operating system, many of them free of charge. If you intend to do any somewhat serious work with a computer, the first thing you need is a decent text editor. This is like a hammer for a carpenter. Do yourself a favour, find a nice one which you like, and learn to use it. Editors like `nano` do work for smaller tasks, but you will sooner or later meet their limitations. To google for a choice of editors, search "programmer's editor for XXX", where XXX is your operating system.